# Major number for ttyO0 device file

Tags: linux-kernel, tty, uart, beagleboneblack

We are using beaglebone black based custom board,
In a process of making device file static for fast bootup,
I am looking in to serial driver  omap-serial.c(drivers/tty/serial/omap-serial.c) to **understand driver's major number allocation**, It seems serial driver's major number is allocated dynamically because i dont see any hardcoded major number,

I tried to follow the serial_omap_init() function but i didnt understand how registration is done and **at what point major number for ttyO0 is assigned**.
I also followed function serial_omap_probe() but only to get lost into the kernel code.
I also checked tty_io.c but that too didnt help, i think, i don't understand this platform driver structure and because of which i am not able to follow,

Any pointer/reference which would help me understand it ?

Comment: What is the kernel version?

Comment: Thank you for attention, it is "3.8.13".

Comment: Why not using kernel's **devtmpfs**?

Comment: Device creation every time during bootup would be time consuming isn't it ? Instead static device files will be in RFS and it will eliminate device file creation time during bootup, isn't it ?

Comment: Have you measured that time penalty? Device creation runs at kernel level and not on user space level, so it shouldn't be that time consuming. But I would really like to see the time difference.